# SignalR only available in the active SILO

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Im developing a real time application using SignalR, im using MVC and Angularjs (SILO). Each cshtml page is a SPA. i have an angularjs common service which contains generic operations like delete, post etc.. Also in my common service i introduced signalR. The problem im having is that since the Serivice is only loaded when a SPA loads, so signalR only works in that SPA. What i want is my signalR to be available in my entire application.. what can i do to achieve this?
My Common Service Code

```
 self.hub = $.connection.MyHub;
    var initializeSignalR = function () {
        self.hub.client.addIssue = function (issue) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(issue));
        };
        $.connection.hub.url = "https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            var tenant = sessionStorage.getItem("tenantName");

            if (tenant !== "") {
                self.hub.server.subscribe(tenant);
            } else {
                console.log("Error occured");
            }
        });
    };
    initializeSignalR();
```

And on my SILO i have this

```
viewModelHelper.hub.on('addIssue', function (issueItem) {
    issues.push(issueItem);
});
```

viewModelHelper is my service, lets say if im in SPA Home, signalR methods in SPA Contacts are not excecuted, i understand why, Its because my service is not initialized in that SPA. How can i achieve signalR availability throughtout my app even when the SPA is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have two options:

- Load it again in every SILO by placing your SignalR service reference in shared layout. This can keep your current application structure.
- Change your app to become real Single Page App(SPA) then you can load and reuse just one SignalR connection in entire app. But this will changed so much of your current system. In that way, you can not use cshtml as current, all view layer and some part of logic will be pushed to client side.